# How can i remove duplicated integers using this "removeDuplicate(ArrayList<Integer> list)" method?

Tags: java

> (Remove duplicates) Write a method that removes the duplicate elements from an array list of integers using the following header:
>
> ```
> public static void removeDuplicate(ArrayList<Integer> list)
> ```
>
> Write a test program that prompts the user to enter 10 integers to a list and displays the distinct integers separated by exactly one space.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

class RemoveDuplicates {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(10);
    System.out.print("Enter 10 integers: ");

    while (in.hasNextInt()) {
      list.add(in.nextInt());
    }

    System.out.println("The list is " + list);
  }

  public static void removeDuplicates(ArrayList<Integer> list) {

    int value = 0;

    do {

      if (!list.contains(value) && value != 0) list.add(value);

    } while (value != 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) System.out.print(list.get(i) + " ");
  }
}
```

Comment: There is a data structure called a `Set`. It's a collection that **never** allows duplicates. Add your list to a set and iterate the set. Java JDK contains some sets such as `HashSet`, `LinkedHashSet`, etc. to help you achieve what you want.

Comment: Stack overflow doesn't work like this. It is good that you posted requirements and code; but the final thing is missing. You did not tell us what happens (and what you expected to happen); and thus you didn't ask a question at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**

Op your program will continuously take inputs, so you should restrict your scanner to stop taking inputs when the count reaches to 10.

you should change your while loop

```
while (list.size()<10) {
            list.add(in.nextInt());
        }
```

And then you haven't invoked your method `removeDuplicates(list);`, So you should invoke it after you took inputs like this

`removeDuplicates(list);`

---

Just add it in  [HashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html)  from arraylist it will remove it automatcally

```
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>(listContainDupRec)
```

If you want to order the elements in ascending or descending order, then use [TreeSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html)

Comment: Then you'd lose ordering - that may or may not be important.

Comment: I wasn't especially meaning whether the elements should be in ascending order in the output - I was meaning the order they appear in the input, i.e. use a `LinkedHashSet` to preserve that.

Answer (score 0):

Pass each element to Set, and print it.
Following [example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-list-to-set-arraylist-to-hastset/)  can help you.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class ConvertListToSet
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println("List values .....");
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("1");

    list.add("2");
    list.add("3");
    list.add("4");
    list.add("1");

    for (String temp : list){
        System.out.println(temp);
    }

    Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(list);

    System.out.println("Set values .....");
    for (String temp : set){
        System.out.print(temp+" ");
    }
}
}
```